# How to find which php script sending the mail on centos server

Tags: php, email, logging, centos

Our server has hosted more than 5 websites.

We have checked that you've reached your daily relay quota and mail added in the queue. We have checked that using `mailq | tail -n 1` and get the counts 39342.

How to know which php script is sent the mail?

Comment: Does your hosting provider uses CPanel?

Answer (score 0):

Your mailq|tail -n 1 just lists the number of mails in your outgoing queue. If you look at the complete output of mailq you should see the sender and recipient adresses. These adresses should help identify your php script.